# Stateless vs Stateful wallets

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, wallet, bip32-hd-wallets

**Stateless wallet** are wallets that do not store any information locally on the device.

**Stateful wallets** are wallets that store  information such as index of unused address.

According to my understanding

- Stateful wallets are more efficent as compared to stateless. As stateful wallet store unused address index locally, whenver a user request to generate a new address. They know right unused index, whereas stateless wallet generates addresses from very first index and queries full node whether a address is used or not.
- If stateful wallet lose all his locally stored data, it needs to work from very begining. It is acceptable in case of blockchain that keeps history from very first transaction. But in case of cryptocurrency like iota that prunes history, if stateful wallet lose stored information, it is going to be big problem.
- Stateless wallet needs to do too much computational cost. As if user last unused address is at index = `1000`, it needs to generate all address from index `0` until `1001`.

My questions are

- Which wallets are better stateless or stateful?
- Which wallets are currently common stateless or stateful?
- Example of stateless and stateful wallet?
- If stateless wallet generates address from index 0 until unspent address index is found, and queires from full node, is it compromise privacy of user. As full node came to know what address a user own?

Note that here i am mainly concern about information of unused index.